# write MySQL output to Excel replacing the '\N' with blanks

Tags: mysql

This is my code:

```
SET @FilePath:='C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/';
SET @FullFilePath:=CONCAT(@FilePath,in_AccountID,'.xls');
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ', 
                  "'", @FullFilePath, "'", '  FROM temp_transactionslines order by TransactionID ASC');
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

it writes the result of each a new query into a new excel file which I'm giving new names with the in_AccountID variable. The only problem is that I want to replace the query fields that got null results represented with '\N', with blank values. I read somewhere that inserting this code snippet

```
«FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'»
```

in my SET @sql instruction would do the trick but I'm getting crazy trying the syntax needed to do that, can please someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot write a xls file, it can write a CSV however.

To get empty values instead of `NULL`:

```
SELECT IFNULL(field1,''),IFNULL(field2,'')... INTO OUTFILE ...
```

Comment: If you mean replacing literally the * with that code it does not work also

Comment: specify your problem better and you might get an answer that "works for you"

Comment: I took notice of your advice and submitted a better specified question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975177/how-to-handle-string-functions-inside-select-concat, I hope.